# Utterly failing to get lsp-mode to work via lsp-docker for Ruby using Solargraph

Tags: lsp-mode

I'm working on a Rails project and using Docker containers with a web and a db container.  The Rails files are on the laptop and mounted into the web container.  The web container has the Ruby executable as well as the Gems -- including the Solargraph gem.  The solargraph executable is the one that Bundler generates.

I am using Emacs 28.2 on macOS.  I have the lsp-mode and lsp-docker packages loaded because `features` includes both of those symbols after I visit a Ruby file.  I also have the projectile and projectile-rails packages loaded.  The projectile-rails appears to work because after a visit a Ruby file, `projectile-rails-find-controller` works.  I have a .lsp-docker.yml file at the root of my application:

```yaml
lsp:
  server:
    type: docker
    subtype: image
    name: lsp-docker-ruby-server
    server: "pedzsan/hatred:1.0"
    launch_command: "/root/bin/solargraph stdio"
  mappings:
    - source: "."
      destination: "/hatred"
```

The application is using .git as well as bundler.

What I'm wanting is for the lsp-mode to see the .lsp-bundler.yml file and know that it needs to talk to the solargraph language server via Docker using lsp-docker but I get the feeling that I'm miles off base and missing a very basic concept.  None of the functions in lsp-docker.el seem to be getting called.

The first time I load a Ruby file, I get this message:

```
LSP :: The following servers support current file but do not have automatic installation: ruby-ls sorbet-ls typeprof-ls ruby-syntax-tree-ls steep-ls
```

and `*lsp-log*` has:

```
Command "solargraph stdio" is not present on the path.
Command "srb typecheck --lsp --disable-watchman" is not present on the path.
Command "typeprof --lsp --stdio" is not present on the path.
Command "stree lsp" is not present on the path.
Command "steep langserver --log-level warn" is not present on the path.
```

repeated.

I'm lost and clueless on how lsp-mode figures out to use lsp-docker.  I think that is my first stumbling point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others, this is working for me.  I have this in a separate file that I require via my init files.  I also have `(eval . (lsp t))` in my `.dir-locals.el` in the project's root.

```lisp
(require 'lsp-docker)

;; In the lsp-mode directory (where lsp-mode.el lives) is a
;; subdirectory called "clients".  In there is a list of "clients".  I
;; can't figure these terms out BUT the list below is a list of these
;; "clients" that you want to be enabled inside the client / server /
;; THING that you are defining / creating.  In my case, as far as I
;; know, I want just the Solargraph "client".
;;
;; Actually this list is just a list of packages to `require' at the
;; time the THING is registered -- so... it is much ado about nothing?
(setq lsp-docker-client-packages
    '(lsp-solargraph))

;; From reading, I guess they call the external server the "server"
;; and the piece either inside or outside of Emacs talking to the
;; server, the "client".  But it gets very confusing (keep reading).
;;
;; Emacs has structures which are defined via `cl-defstruct'.
;; `lsp-clients' is a hash of `lsp--client' structures which has a
;; "slot" `server-id' whose comment is: "Unique identifier for
;; representing the client object.".
;;
;; As mentioned `lsp-clients' is a hash (key value pairs) with the
;; keys being the `server-id' (which is also within the structure).
;;
;; With all that in mind, then:
;;
;; :server-id -- needs to be an existing entry in lsp-clients.  You
;;     can see the list and their priorities by executing:
;;
;;         (maphash
;;          (lambda (key value)
;;            (insert (format "%S  %d\n"
;;                            key
;;                            (lsp--client-priority value))))
;;          lsp-clients)
;;
;;     in the *scratch*  buffer.
;;
;; :docker-server-id -- The name or id of the new "client object"
;;     a.k.a. the `server-id'.  The existing entry is found via the
;;     `server-id', updated, and entered as a new client using the
;;     docker-server-id.
;;
;; :server-command -- This string is munged via
;;     `lsp-docker-launch-new-container' into a list of strings which
;;     is used to start the language server inside the Docker
;;     image/container.  Basically it will turn into:
;;
;;         docker run --name TBD1 --rm -i TBD2 TBD3 `server-command'
;;
;;     TBD1 is `docker-container-name'; TBD2 are `path-mappings' that
;;     have been transformed into a list of "-v" options.  TBD3 is
;;     `docker-image-id'
;;
;; `docker-container-name' and `docker-image-id' will be specified below.
;;
(setq lsp-docker-client-configs
      '((:server-id ruby-ls :docker-server-id rubyls-docker :server-command "/root/bin/solargraph stdio")))

(lsp-docker-init-clients
 :path-mappings '(("/Users/pedz/Source/hatred" . "/hatred"))
 :docker-image-id "pedzsan/hatred:1.0"
 :docker-container-name "docker-ruby-lsp"
 :priority 10
 :client-packages lsp-docker-client-packages
 :client-configs lsp-docker-client-configs)

(provide 'lsp-docker-start)
```